# running into someone after vacation

Tags: expressions, idioms, conversation

[image: this is my conversation exercise]

for the question 16, I don't know either using "How was your break?" or "What's going on". 
And Q20,"what about you?" and "what are you up to?" seem able to use?
Could someone explain their usages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is to look at the response to figure out what the missing preceding phrase has to be.  For 16, "It was really fun" wouldn't be a response to any of the options except "How was your break?"  For instance, the only proper response to "What can I do for you?" is an answer like "Nothing." or "You can give me a ride to the airport."

For 20, the response is "I went to the beach", which is in the past tense.  That wouldn't be a reply to a present tense question like "What's happening?" (i.e., "What is happening?") or "How are you?"